# Re-export a default export

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-6

What is the best way to re-export a default export from another file?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
export Button from './Button/Button';
```

Apparently this is not valid EcmaScript syntax (however it used to work in older Babel versions).

As a result I want to `import {Button} from 'components';`

Is there a better way, maybe a one-liner? ES6 syntax would be preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: Why? Why not just `import {Button} from 'components/Button'` or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-export default in ES 6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999282/re-export-default-in-es-6-modules)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `export { x as y }` syntax:

```
export { default as Button } from './Button/Button';
```

> I'd like to do something like this:
>
> `export Button from './Button/Button';`

There is a stage 1 proposal for this syntax: https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-more-export-from

Comment: Unfortunately `export { default as y } from './m'` does not work for me. I have `export default function () { /* ... */ }` in *m.js*. With the `export { default as ...` statement in *i.js*, I try `import { y } from './i'` in another file, but y is undefined. I use babel 6 require-hook and polyfill in node 4.2.

Comment: Nevermind, found the reason: The [add-module-exports plugin](https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports) is the reason for `export { default as x } from '...'` not to work.