# Re-export default in ES 6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

In ES6, is it possible to shorten the following code. I have an `App.js` file and an `index.js`.

**index.js**

```
import App from './App';

export default App;
```

Something like this

**index.js**

```
export default App from './App.js'
```

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-default-from

Answer (score 203, accepted):

If you use [`proposal-export-default-from` Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-export-default-from.html) (which is a part of [`stage-1` preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/)), you'll be able to re-export default using the following code:

```
export default from "./App.js"
```

For more information see [the ECMAScript proposal](https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-default-from#exporting-a-default-as-default).

---

Another way (without this plugin) is:

```
export { default as App } from "./App.js"
```

---

The above is a very common practice when separate files, each with its own `export`, have all something in common, for example, `utils`, so if, for example, one would want to import 3 *utility* functions, instead of having to write multiple *imports*:

```js
import util_a from 'utils/util_a' 
import util_b from 'utils/util_b' 
import util_c from 'utils/util_c'
```

One could import any of the utilities in a single-line:

```js
import { util_a, util_b , util_c } from 'utils'
```

By creating an `index.js` file in the `/utils` folder and import all the defaults of all the utilities there and re-export, so the `index` file will serve as the "gateway" for all imports related to that folder.

Comment: ```export { default as MyModule } from "./my-modue.js";
const { oneSmallFunction } = MyModule
``` Just going extra mile.

Comment: @AlanDong your suggestions looks like a very valid solution to me. Why don't you post it as an answer ?

Comment: Seems like the `export default from` proposal didn't make it; using that Babel plugin is probably not a good idea.

Comment: The better answer is from @Fernando. As for this accepted one, it is overkill to use additional proposal babel plugin just to have more syntax sugar for a symetric re-export of default.

Answer (score 117):

This is a bit of repetition from the previous answers, but to clarify the difference in two options:

### **1. Default export**

(This appears to be what OP wants)

```js
// index.ts
export { default } from './App'
```

Then, in a different file:

```js
import App from './index'
```

### **2. Named export**

```js
export { default as App } from './App'
```

Then, in another file:

```js
import { App } from './index'
```

### Bonus: named → default export

If `./App` uses a named export, but you want to re-export it as a default export, you can do that too:

```
export { App as default } from './App'
```

Then, in another file:

```
import App from './index'
```

These will work with `react` as vsync's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56413083/revisions) states.

### Bonus #2: export everything

Say you have a file that exports multiple items:

```
// App.ts
export const first = 1

export const second = 2

const final = 3

export default final
```

You can then re-export them directly:

```
// index.ts
export * from './App'
```

You can now import these easily:

```
import final, { first, second } from './index'
```

### Bonus #3: `*` import

You can import all variables exported by another file as a single variable.

```
// index.ts
import * as App from './App'

App.first === 1 // true
```

Comment: Definitely #1. So, you'll get like `import MainComponent, { OtherComponents } from './that-component';`

Comment: nice answer, but not for the question. The question is connected to js, not ts.

Comment: I had undevoted this a last year I guess. I ran into the same issue and got here and it helped me again. I wish I could upvote it again!

Comment: Glad it's at least useful when you stumble upon it @RavindraThorat!

Answer (score 17):

```
import App from './App';

export default App;
```

## ⬇

#### Babel 7 (with [`@babel/preset-react`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react)) can transform the below:

```
export { default as App } from './App.js';
```

---

Related discussions:

- TC39 proposal:
  https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-default-from#common-concerns

Answer (score 7):

The only working solution is :

```
import App from './App';

export default App;
```

If you export your module like this

```
export { default as App } from './App.js';
```

Then it's not a default export anymore and you'll get an error if you try to import it as a default import.

Comment: As [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59002206/7869175) states, you can also do `export { default } from './App'`.

Comment: @FernandoRojo no, that's not working

Comment: I use it all the time, so there must be something up with your usage.

Answer (score -3):

```
import App from './App';
export default (App);
```

This work for me in default 'create-react-app' application