# Export * as * using ES6Modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Is there something like:

```
export * as * from 'myJavaScriptFile.js'
```

**I seem to want**

> "A way to export all variables which are exported from a file to be
>   re-exported from another file - not with a new reference but whatever
>   reference it was exported in the first place"

**NOT like below: because there is a new reference(allStuff)**

```
import default, * as allStuff from 'myJavaScriptFile.js';
export { allStuff };
```

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999282/re-export-default-in-es-6-modules

Comment: `export * from './file'` exists, to `export * as` you have to first import and than export const

Answer (score 2):

you're looking for this:

```js
export * from './typescript-file';
export * from './javascript-file';
```

This will re-export everything exported from that file

This is typically used in barrel files (`index.ts`)

Comment: question is not about ts

Comment: the action is the same

Comment: Indeed, there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You'd just use a star export - without `as` keyword:

```
export * from 'myJavaScriptFile.js';
```