# TypeScript export default from another module

Tags: typescript

How to export default from another module in one line?

```js
export * from './another'; //Can't export default from another.
```

```js
export m from './another';
export default m;  //That's ok.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-export default in ES 6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999282/re-export-default-in-es-6-modules)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
export { default } from './another';
```