# Cannot export module, but import is fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Why this work

```
import ActionButton from './components/atom/ActionButton'
```

And this not?

```
export ActionButton from './components/atom/ActionButton'
```

The line above give me the error:

> Cannot find name 'ActionButton'.ts(2304)

My directory structure

```
.
├── components
│   ├── atom
│   │   ├── ActionButton
│   │   │   ├── ActionButton.spec.tsx
│   │   │   ├── ActionButton.stories.tsx
│   │   │   ├── ActionButton.styles.tsx
│   │   │   ├── ActionButton.tsx
│   │   │   └── index.ts
```

Where on `index.ts` I have

```
export { default } from './ActionButton'
```

Comment: Why do you want to write `export ActionButton from './components/atom/ActionButton'`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-export default in ES 6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999282/re-export-default-in-es-6-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to `export { default as ActionButton } from './components/atom/ActionButton'` as ActionButton has no named export.

Comment: Is there some way to I do `export ActionButton from './components/atom/ActionButton'` or `export { ActionButton } from './components/atom/ActionButton'`?

Comment: Inside ActionButton update its export to `export { ActionButton }`. Remove the default export and use a named one.