# export {default} from "./Button" in VS Code in index.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have noticed that some file structures follow the pattern like:

/component

-Button

- index.js
- Button.js
- button.module.css

Normally what I see is the following:

in Button.js

```
const Button = () => {...} 
export default Button
```

in index.js

```
export {default} from './Button'
```

Why that export in index.js looks like a named export. My Button component was exported as a default.

Is VS code doing and auto import where my component goes from default export to named export? Or is this a React thing? ES6?

Comment: It's so someone can import the component using `path/to/button` instead of `path/to/button/Button.js`

Comment: It's an ES6 module thing, it just means export the default from "./Button" as the default from this whole module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59002206/3001761, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export